# How could I make the SurfaceView and Button have a different orientation in a Activity

Tags: android

I hava a simple program about video recording .
I use the surfaceView to show the preview screen.
and I also want to put some buttons on the screen.

I put all the component mentioned above into a XML file which is "ipcam.xml"

I use MediaRecorder , SurfaceView , SurfaceHolder to complete this program
because the preview screen does not orientate correctly when I rotate my phone.
so I use "setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);"
but , the button in the program is always in LANDSCAPE direction . 
it will not auto change direction when I rotate my phone , but the preview is ok!!

so is there anyway to solve this problem.

Thank you all very much in advance.

you can see this picture , I put my phone in vertical direction
the preview screen seems OK 
 but the button is in horizontal direction , i don't want it.

https://newslab.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~poc7667/123.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_title"
      android:screenOrientation="landscape"
      android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` on your activity's configuration in the manifest.xml?